# MediaLibraryPickerField : how to pick only provided Content types?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

MediaLibraryPickerField has a seeting named "DisplayedContentTypes". I think it is used to provide only required content types that I want my picker field to select and render. But somehow it is not working. 
E.g: I want to select only Image,OEmbed types. I put it in the settings area's text box:

> Content Types and Parts
>
> [Image,OEmbed]
>
> A comma separated value of all the content types or content parts to
>   display.

and saved it. But it is still picking all kind of media and rendering them.

Any thing I might be missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue here https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21051
There is no fix yet although.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the property exists but is not used. 
We should try to implement a filter, as it is done for the content picker field.